# extract JSON key value in dataweave

Tags: mule, dataweave

Hi I have a dataweave with some key values. { "abc":"1", "xyz":"8" }

I have a flow variable fvTest with this data. { "Req": { "animal": "dog", "plant": "basil","test":"" } }

I want the data from fvTest to be added into the above dataweave but in this format and want to ignore nulls { "abc":"1", "xyz":"8", "data.animal":"dog", "data.plant":"basil" }

How to do this.

Answer (score 0):

`mapObject` performs a mapping across the key value pairs of an object, so can be used to both rename the key to data.key and to filter the empty values.
This can then be concatenated with `++` to the other set of keys and values.

```
 keyValues ++ (flowVars.fvTest.Req mapObject ('data.$$': $ ) when ($ != null and $ != ""))
```

Should do what you describe.